# Can I Copy and paste to the location of the Mouse

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I keep copying a sequence clip and when I hit command v it seems to just paste it in a random location after I've positioned the mouse/sequence bar. Why does this happen? 
Many thanks

Comment: I just tried that in the VSE and it pastes at the current frame. Are you referring to the Video Sequence Editor?

Comment: sorry yes this is within the video editor

Comment: OK, try this. Open a new file, switch the the VSE and add an image and copy thte strip with Ctrl+C. Then set the current frame to 88 and paste Ctrl+v. If that works then build up to the conditions to where you saw the issue. Is this Blender 2.79 on Windows?

Comment: 2.79 on OSX that does work better it seems, not precisely but only a few frames back and on the sequence space above rather than somewhere entirely different